# Percentage labels in pie chart with ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

I'm working now in a statistics project and recently started with R. I have some problems with the visualization. I found a lot of different tutorials about how to add percentage labels in pie charts, but after one hour of trying I still don't get it. Maybe something is different with my data frame so that this doesn't work?

It's a data frame with collected survey answers, so I'm not allowed to publish them here. The column in question (geschäftliche_lage) is a factor with three levels ("Gut", "Befriedigend", "Schlecht"). I want to add percentage labels for each level.

I used the following code in order to create the pie chart:

```
dataset %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= "", fill = geschäftliche_lage)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "count", width = 1, color = "white") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00BA38", "#619CFF", "#F8766D")) +
  theme_void()
```

This code gives me the desired pie chart, but without percentage labels. As soon as a I try to add percentage labels, everything is messed up. Do you know a clean code for adding percentage labels?

If you need more information or data, just let me know!

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mtcars` as example data. Maybe this what your are looking for:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = "", fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(stat= "count", width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..count.. / sum(..count..))), stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00BA38", "#619CFF", "#F8766D")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I used now this code: `dataset %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= "", fill = factor(geschäftliche_lage))) +
  geom_bar(stat= "count", width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..count / sum(..count..))),
            stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00BA38", "#619CFF", "#F8766D")) +
  theme_void()`

Now I've got the following error: "Error in number(x = x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix,  : object '..count' not found"

Comment: Hi @Nicosc. You missed the ".." at the end of `..count..` in `scales::percent(..count / ....`

Comment: Great.  If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.